# Trouble understanding Excel Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am new to using Excel formulas.
I have an Excel with alot of formulas like

> =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B9,Data[[#All],[Field Location]:[On Production Date]],4,0),"")

I understand IFERROR function and VLOOKUP function.

What makes trouble understanding is table array in VLOOKUP function which is

> Data[[#All],[Field Location]:[On Production Date]]

What this table array represents and how can I create something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are structured references. You can read more at:

[Using structured references with Excel tables](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-structured-references-with-Excel-tables-a547e45e-3589-4417-b611-abb7e5d3f912)

> Structured references make it much easier and more intuitive to work
>   with table data when you are using formulas that reference a table–
>   either portions of a table or the entire table. They are especially
>   useful because table data ranges often change, and the cell references
>   for structured references adjust automatically. This minimizes the
>   need to rewrite formulas as rows and columns are added and deleted in
>   a table, or when external data is refreshed.

Answer (score 3):

```
Data[[#All],[Field Location]:[On Production Date]]
```

is the equivalent of giving a range. $Field Location2:$On Production Date1000, ($A2:$B1000)
assuming there are 1000 rows in your table. Writing the formula in this way will automatically include any new rows added to your Data table.

Data[[#Header],[Field Location]] is equivalent to $Field Location1. Or $A$1.

Answer (score 2):

In Excel, you can give names to certain ranges. Just mark an area, and then on the top left (below the menu), you can enter a name in a drop-down-box.

This name can then subsequently be used in referencing the range, like it is shown in your formula.

This is more intuitive than writing `A2:G98`, and even more, when you insert new rows into the range, then they will automatically be included.